# Search given value in table and return value from first row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In this scenario I can see that the last time `Mickey` appears on the rota is 06/01/2015 and say `Sue` last appears on 10/01/2015.

Is there a formula that can automatically collate that information for me. The Formula would need to return the Date that 'Mickey' last appeared.

```
Date        Staff 1 Staff2  Staff 3 Staff 4 Staff 5 Staff 6 Staff 7   
01/01/2015  Mark    Peter   Dave    Sue     Claire  Steve   James    
02/01/2015  Dave    Andrea  Mark    Peter   James   Steve   Sue    
03/01/2015  Sue     Mark    Peter   Claire  Steve   Dave    Claire    
04/01/2015  Claire  Julie   Dave    Mark    Peter   Sue     Bob    
05/01/2015  Mark    Bill    Sue     Claire  James   Steve   Peter    
06/01/2015  Peter   Mickey  Mark    James   Steve   Claire  Dave    
07/01/2015  Peter   Steve   James   Mark    Claire  Sue     Dave    
08/01/2015  Mark    James   Peter   Claire  Dave    Steve   Sue    
09/01/2015  Claire  Sue     Julie   Dave    Mark    Peter   Steve    
10/01/2015  Steve   Andrea  Dave    Peter   Claire  Mark    Sue     
11/01/2015  Peter   Paul    James   Steve   Stuart  Claire  Julie
```

Comment: I've already tried vlookup but I don't know how to the last entry when there several cells in the column containing the same text. I can, for instance in this scenario look up '05/01/2015' and find that 'staff3' was Sue, but I want to search 'Sue' and get the date she last appeared. I just cant do it Cheers

Comment: Just to add to the last comment, I have managed to get the required answer before, but I could only do it by using macros as well as lookup formulas but it was very long winded. I just feel there must be a cleaner, simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want a macro, I'd recommend to look into conditional formatting and use that to highlight either all duplicates of a name entered in a special cell (say J1), or the date(s) for the row containing the name. The second is slightly more complex.

1. - Select all the cells containing names, starting at B2  (Mark)
   - Find "Conditional formatting" in Excel (location depends on version)
   - Select the type to be "Formula"
   - Enter `=(B2=$J$1)` as the formula and then select how to format the cell as the formula evaluates to TRUE (the names match).
2. - Select the Date column (besides the title) starting at A2
   - Do the same as above, but use the formula `=search($J$1,concatenate(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2))>0` instead.
3. - Enter the formula from 2. in cell `I2`, and "copy down" into the cells below it.
       `#VALUE` will appear for those rows that do NOT contain the name you type in J1

Besides from other similarly complex (or even more so) ways to do it, you might have only macro solutions as "better" option.

NOTE: Some versions of Excel has problems with inserted rows (at top or bottom) in tables that have conditional formatting. Insert rows in the middle of the table only - then sort the table to get it in a order you like.

Comment: Thanks Hannu if that's the only way, then i'll have to do it using the macro as you said. Much appreciated though

Comment: #3 added above.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the time. I've started on the long winded macros now. at least the outcome is what's needed